# Regex to only match group when inside of certain characters

Tags: regex

I have this regex `{=\((COMMENT|TYPE)\):(.\X+?)}` that matches certain strings but I only want it to do that match when the string it finds is inside a certain string. So for example I have this https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lHOj.png input where it does what I want, but I only want it to match them when they are in between `{=(SETTINGS):` and the ending `}` so it would not should not match the ones underlined in red in this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLRvt.png

Comment: You must tag regex-related questions with the language you are using. Different languages have different regex capabilities.

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/zLxiHB/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would approach this is with two regular expressions ***and requires no special capabilities and should work with most languages***. The first regular expression extracts the contents between the opening `{=(SETTINGS):` and closing `}`. This is only possible if we assume that between these opening and closing sequence of characters we can rely on that the `{` and `}` occur as they do, i.e. only singly nested within. Then the contents between these opening and closing sequences are 0 or more sequences of:

1. 1 or more characters other than `{` or `}`
2. A `{` followed by 0 or more characters other than `{` or `}` followed by a `}`

Once the contents has been extracted a second regex can then do the rest of the work.  The following is coded in Python (you did not specify a language, so I am free to choose). I am specifying `(?x)` at the start of the regular expressions. This turns on *verbose* mode, which allows whitespace to be ignored allowing my regex to span across multiple lines and to have comments so as to be self-commenting.

Next time please do not use images. Instead copy and paste the actual text into your question so that I could have easily created the input string. I have therefore used my own, shorter input.

First regex:

```
{=\(SETTINGS\):((?:[^{}]+|(?:{[^{}}]*}))*)}
```

[First regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BfqzTA/1/)

Second regex:

```
{=\((?:COMMENT|TYPE)\):[^}]*}
```

[Second regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yaWi9V/1)

```py
import re

s = """{=(SETTINGS):
{=(prefix):!}
{=(COMMENT):This is a comment}
{=(prefix):!}
{=(TYPE):number}
{=(prefix):!}
}
{=(COMMENT):This is to be ignored}
"""

pattern = r'''(?x)
{=\(SETTINGS\):       # {=(SETTINGS):
(                     # start of capture group 1
  (?:                 # start of non-capturing group
      [^{}]+          # one or more non {} characters
    |                 # or
      (?:{[^{}}]*})   # balanced {} expression
  )                   # end of non capturing group
  *                   # 0 or more times
)                     # end of capture group 1
}                     # }
'''

m = re.search(pattern, s)
if m:
    s2 = m[1]
    pattern2 = r'''(?x)
{=\((?:COMMENT|TYPE)\):  # {=(COMMENT): or {=(TYPE):
[^}]*                    # 0 or more non-} characters
}                        # }
'''
    matches = re.findall(pattern2, s2)
    print(matches)
```

Prints:

```
['{=(COMMENT):This is a comment}', '{=(TYPE):number}']
```